# Get GCC's list of versions from ftp://ftp.gnu.org using ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, ftp

Today I would like to make ruby script to parse this gcc download link: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/

I would like my code parse this page and give me list of all gcc version (include gcc text).

I would like to have into array:
["gcc-10.1.0","gcc-2.95"] ...etc. In one word, all gcc dir's name. Or is it possible without parsing?

Comment: One option is to use Net::FTP, list the directory, then select only those entries that start with "gcc" and end with a number.

Answer (score 0):

That "download page" is not a normal website, it is an FTP directory (that's why the URL starts with `ftp://`). Your web browser makes it look like a website, but FTP is essentially a network directory that you read files from.

Ruby's stdlib has a [Net::FTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html) class that you should be able to use to list the files you want.

Comment: Oh thanks ! Perfect ! Just another question. I have doing that : files = ftp.list('gcc-*'). This return me, all, included file with extensions. But i just would like to add dirs list. How can i parse better?

Comment: @JulienLondais Please look at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html